# AngularJS fadein applies to first element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, fadein

I have the following template with an ng repeat and list items. I am trying to keep one item open per time and fade it in when clicked.
Right now only the first list item fades in, even though the descHelp id is used for all the items.Any ideas?

template:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="parts in data track by $index">
  <li id="title" ng-click='setItem($index);'>
    <div  class="hblinks" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails; " >
      <span class="sb-text-title">the title</span>
    </div>
    <div id ="descHelp"  ng-show="showDetails && $index == itemIndex">
```

in the directive:

```
$scope.setItem=function(item) {
  $scope.itemIndex=item;
  var target = $element.find('#descHelp');
  target.fadeIn( 600 );
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id, use a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

`$element.find('#descHelp')` will only return yout the first element with that id, and not all of then. You should use classes, id's must be used only once.

You can use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` to force only one div is present in the DOM with that id as a workarround, but i don really recommend.

Better build an unique id using $index object like id="descHelp-{{$index}}"

Answer (score 1):

Give unique id using $index:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="parts in data track by $index">
  <li id="title" ng-click='setItem($index);'>
    <div  class="hblinks" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails; " >
      <span class="sb-text-title">the title</span>
    </div>
    <div id ="descHelp_{{$index}}"  ng-show="showDetails && $index == itemIndex">
```

And pass it to controller

```
$scope.setItem=function(item, index) {
  $scope.itemIndex=item;
  var target = $element.find('#descHelp_' + index);
  target.fadeIn( 600 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it is working most of the times but not always. For example if I expand-collapse-expand the same element, in the second expand it won't fade in.